# How do I set the current selection in a QListWidget to none?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have a list of items in a QListWidget and I want to make it so that when a certain action is performed the current selected item is deselected and no other item in the list is selected, like how the list appears when the program first starts.

I tried `setCurrentItem(NULL);` but that just creates a segmentation fault

Comment: Try: `selectionModel()->clear();`

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you, this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the current item you need to clear the selection model. Here is how you do that:

```
selectionModel()->clear();
```

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I asked but it has highlighted other issues in my project. Now there is a segmentation fault whenever I click and drag on an item. I have included the full code and a better description here if there's a chance you could take a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683855/qlistwidget-causing-segmentation-fault-when-clicking-and-dragging-across-multipl