# QListWidget causing segmentation fault when clicking and dragging across multiple items

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have a QListWidget with multiple items each acting like a button responding when clicked on. I have run into a problem where if you click on one item and drag the mouse to anywhere else on the screen apart from the item you clicked on then the program will cause a segmentation fault and crash. Does anyone know how I might fix this?

I have included all the code that I have written below, although this code also relies on proprietary code that I don't think I can post here

**window.cc**

```
#include "globals.h"

#include <QLabel>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QListWidgetItem>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include "windowheader.h"

namespace{

class statisticsTab : public QWidget {
public:
    statisticsTab();
private:
    QGridLayout * layout;
    QLabel * title;
    QLabel * userListTitle;
    QLabel * branchListTitle;
    UserListWidget * userList;
    BranchListWidget * branchList;
    QListWidget * statsPage;
};

inline statisticsTab::statisticsTab() : QWidget() {
    layout = new QGridLayout();
    cur_repo = new GITPP::REPO();

    title = new QLabel("Repository Statistics");
    title->setStyleSheet("QLabel {font-weight: bold;}");
    layout->addWidget(title, 0, 0, 1, 2);

    userListTitle = new QLabel("Contributors");
    layout->addWidget(userListTitle, 1, 0, 1, 1);

    branchListTitle = new QLabel("Branches");
    layout->addWidget(branchListTitle, 1, 1, 1, 1);

    statsPage = new QListWidget();
    layout->addWidget(statsPage, 3, 0, 1, 2, Qt::AlignTop);
    QListWidgetItem * statsPageDefault = new QListWidgetItem(QString("Click on a contributor or branch to get started!"), 0, 0);
    statsPage->addItem(statsPageDefault);

    userList = new UserListWidget(statsPage);
    layout->addWidget(userList, 2, 0, 1, 1);

    branchList = new BranchListWidget(statsPage);
    layout->addWidget(branchList, 2, 1, 1, 1);

    if(cur_repo != nullptr) {
        GITPP::COMMITS commits = cur_repo->commits();
        std::vector <std::string> contributors;

        for(auto commit : commits) {
            contributors.push_back(commit.author());
        }

        std::sort(contributors.begin(), contributors.end());
        contributors.erase(unique(contributors.begin(), contributors.end()), contributors.end());

        for(auto contributor : contributors) {
            QString contributorName = QString::fromStdString(contributor);
            QListWidgetItem * contributorNameItem = new QListWidgetItem(contributorName);
            userList->addItem(contributorNameItem);
        }

        GITPP::BRANCHES branches = cur_repo->branches();

        for(auto branch : branches) {
            QListWidgetItem * branchName = new QListWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(branch.name()), 0, 0);
            branchList->addItem(branchName);
        }
    } else {
        QListWidgetItem * branchListDefault = new QListWidgetItem(QString("No branches found"), 0, 0);
        branchList->addItem(branchListDefault);

        QListWidgetItem * userListDefault = new QListWidgetItem(QString("No users found"), 0, 0);
        userList->addItem(userListDefault);
    }

    setLayout(layout);
}

INSTALL_TAB(statisticsTab, "Statistics");

}
```

**windowheader.h**

```
#ifndef WINDOWHEADER_H
#define WINDWOHEADER_H

#include <QListWidget>
#include <string>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include "globals.h"

class UserListWidget : public QListWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    UserListWidget(QListWidget * statsPage);

private slots:
    void updateStatsPage();
private:
    QListWidget * statsPage;
};

inline UserListWidget::UserListWidget(QListWidget * statsPageArg) : QListWidget() {
    connect(this, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()), this, SLOT(updateStatsPage()));
    statsPage = statsPageArg;
}

inline void UserListWidget::updateStatsPage() {
    GITPP::CONFIG config = cur_repo->config();
    GITPP::COMMITS commits = cur_repo->commits();


    QString statsTitle = QString("Here are some stats about the user ") + this->currentItem()->text();
    QListWidgetItem * statsTitleItem = new QListWidgetItem(statsTitle);
    statsPage->clear();
    statsPage->addItem(statsTitleItem);

    for(auto thing : config) {
        QString statsInfo = QString::fromStdString(thing.name());
        QListWidgetItem * statsInfoItem = new QListWidgetItem(statsInfo);
        statsPage->addItem(statsInfoItem);
    }

    selectionModel()->clear();
}

class BranchListWidget : public QListWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    BranchListWidget(QListWidget * statsPage);

private slots:
    void updateStatsPage();
private:
    QListWidget * statsPage;
};

inline BranchListWidget::BranchListWidget(QListWidget * statsPageArg) : QListWidget() {
    connect(this, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()), this, SLOT(updateStatsPage()));
    statsPage = statsPageArg;
}

inline void BranchListWidget::updateStatsPage() {
    GITPP::CONFIG config = cur_repo->config();
    GITPP::COMMITS commits = cur_repo->commits();

    QString statsTitle = QString("Here are some stats about the branch ") + this->currentItem()->text();
    QListWidgetItem * statsTitleItem = new QListWidgetItem(statsTitle);
    statsPage->clear();
    statsPage->addItem(statsTitleItem);

    for(auto thing : config) {
        QString statsInfo = QString::fromStdString(thing.name());
        QListWidgetItem * statsInfoItem = new QListWidgetItem(statsInfo);
        statsPage->addItem(statsInfoItem);
    }

    selectionModel()->clear();
}

#endif
```

Valgrind output:

```
==9475== Invalid read of size 8
==9475==    at 0x1158B5: UserListWidget::updateStatsPage() (in /home/alexis/Desktop/programming/uni_work/comp_2811/cw2/ui_cw3/2811_gui)
==9475==    by 0x5F5D5E8: QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x5F5D5E8: QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x5EE0BE6: QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged(QItemSelection const&, QItemSelection const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x5EE544A: QItemSelectionModel::emitSelectionChanged(QItemSelection const&, QItemSelection const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x5EE8F91: QItemSelectionModel::select(QItemSelection const&, QFlags<QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlag>) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x54DF9B4: QListView::setSelection(QRect const&, QFlags<QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlag>) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x54C6B3E: QAbstractItemView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x54E6386: QListView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x52B8277: QWidget::event(QEvent*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x53A0A0D: QFrame::event(QEvent*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x54C7502: QAbstractItemView::viewportEvent(QEvent*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==9475== 
==9475== 
==9475== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==9475==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==9475==    at 0x1158B5: UserListWidget::updateStatsPage() (in /home/alexis/Desktop/programming/uni_work/comp_2811/cw2/ui_cw3/2811_gui)
==9475==    by 0x5F5D5E8: QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x5F5D5E8: QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x5EE0BE6: QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged(QItemSelection const&, QItemSelection const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x5EE544A: QItemSelectionModel::emitSelectionChanged(QItemSelection const&, QItemSelection const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x5EE8F91: QItemSelectionModel::select(QItemSelection const&, QFlags<QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlag>) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x54DF9B4: QListView::setSelection(QRect const&, QFlags<QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlag>) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x54C6B3E: QAbstractItemView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x54E6386: QListView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x52B8277: QWidget::event(QEvent*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x53A0A0D: QFrame::event(QEvent*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
==9475==    by 0x54C7502: QAbstractItemView::viewportEvent(QEvent*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.1)
```

Comment: @drescherjm Okay, I added all the code that I have written

Comment: Have you tried running the program in a debugger and looking at the stack trace at the point of the segmentation fault? I imagine the stack trace would prove insightful. If you have the stack trace or can get it, please add it to your question. Thanks!

Comment: @LouisLangholtz I've added the Valgrind output, I hope it's helpful

Comment: I believe you have a null pointer dereference in updateStatsPage. Does it crash if `selectionModel()->clear();`  is commented out?

Comment: Yes, `this->currentItem()->text()`, I just found it! I added a check for it and now it works perfectly! Thank you :)

Comment: I dd not see that but do now. It was off to the right of the screen. Yes you have to make sure there is a current item before the dereference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the segmentation fault is occurring within the `UserListWidget::updateStatsPage()` method.

Given the limited information available and that you've said this problem occurs when you drag the mouse off of the item originally clicked, **I suspect** that `this->currentItem()` is returning a null pointer in the line of code where the method calls `this->currentItem()->text()`. When you first click on a widget list item, I'm guessing that the `UserListWidget::updateStatsPage()` method is called with a non-null pointer being returned from `this->currentItem()`. But then you drag the mouse and if you drag it off of the current item, another `itemSelectionChanged()` signal is generated. If you've dragged the mouse off of the `QListWidget` entirely, I imagine the signal would be called at a time when `this->currentItem()` will return a null pointer indicating that nothing is selected.

Try checking whether `this->currentItem()` is null and only dereference it if not null.